# How to display a custom layout that slides from right and take user input in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

I have a fragment with a form. One of the controls is a button. So when I click on the button I want a custom view to slide from right like a dialog. The view may have a custom width and custom height. I want the layout to be positioned at center.  So whatever I do on the view I want the value to pass to the parent fragment. How can I do this? Should I use a fragment or a dialog.

I would appreciate if anyone could show me the basic structure of the code.

This is how I have made the call:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout box = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.box_container);
            Animation errorSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.box_anim);
            box.startAnimation(errorSlide);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slide animation for this. for the sake of help I am adding little chunk of code. You can modify then according to your need.

Below is the animation that will be needed. Create anim folder inside res and create animation animation inside the folder and give it a suitable name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="75%p"
    android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

Create a layout xml as mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.awaheed.testingproject.MainActivity">

<View
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/slidder"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Slide view"
    android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And use below activity code

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final View slideView = findViewById(R.id.slidder);


   findViewById(R.id.btn_slide).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Animation animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                   R.anim.slide);


           slideView.startAnimation(animSlide);
       }
   });
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Okay I did what you said. Except in place of your view object, I created a another .xml layout file with linear layout and tried to call that layout. I got a NullPointerException. Any idea??

Comment: when are getting null pointer exception? can you please post the code you tried?

Comment: I have added the code in the question. I tried your code and it worked. What I want to do is I already have a fragment with its layout file. I'm trying to call another layout file on top of the fragment with its own sets of views. How can i do that? I want to overlay this view on top of my fragment view. also your view slides from left to right. I want my view to slide from right to left(kinda like a drawer layout)